# Запуск sqlite JDBC на Android

Tags: android, sqlite, jdbc

Всем привет, я настроил JDBC sqlite в проекте Intellij IDEA на ПК. Теперь пробую чисто ради спортивного интереса настроить ее на Android в приложение AIDE. Я создаю Java проект и могу запускать Java проекты в Android. Собственно, я как обычно подключил sqlite-jdbc.jar к проекту и проверил класс `org.sqlite.JDBC` - он присутствует. Я пытаюсь использовать следующий код для соединения с БД, собственно, она должна появиться по пути `/sdcard/test.db`:

```
Connection dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC.PREFIX + "/sdcard/test.db");
```

Но я получаю ошибку что подходящий драйвер не найден. Окей, нахожу информацию, что перед использованием необходимо загрузить класс `JDBC`. Перед `getConnection` пишу `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` и получаю ошибку, что нативная библиотека `libsqlitejdbc.so` не найдена в `nativeDirectories`. В Android библиотеки находятся в `/system/lib` и `/vendor/lib`. Я выясняю какая либа мне нужна с помощью

```
OSInfo.getNativeLibFolderPathForCurrentOS()
```

И получаю `Linux/androidarm`. Захожу в jar и вырываю из него `Linux/android-arm/libsqlitejdbc.so` и закидываю в папку /system/lib` дав разрешение как и всем соседям (буква Г). Запускаю программу и получаю интересную ошибку

```
dlopen failed: library '/system/lib/libsqlitejdbc.so' needed or dlopened by '/system/lib/libnativeloader.so' is not accessible for the namespace 'classloader-namespace'
```

Что делать?) Повторюсь, чисто спортивный интерес)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC в *vanilla* Android не работает. Необходимо портировать JDBC драйвер под Android.

Например, можно использовать [SQLDroid](https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid)

Comment: Большое спасибо))